# How to implement external memory for the "memory augmented neural network"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to implement the **memory-augmented neural network** using MMA 11.3. 
The memory-augmented neural network in based on the [paper here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06065.pdf). There are implementations using `TensorFlow`, as shown [here](https://github.com/hmishra2250/NTM-One-Shot-TF/blob/master/MANN/Model.py#L118).

So far, I can build a netgraph that is composed of a controller using LSTM. I am not sure how to keep an external memory that can be addressed by the LSTM controller using the deep learning modules provided by MMA.

I appreciate your attention and would be really grateful if you could offer any insights for this task.